# Include unpersisted Hibernate data on Grails Domain queries

Tags: hibernate, grails

Sometimes in Grails Service I need to handle many transaction among two to three tables:

```
class MyService {
    void saveOwner(Map params) {
        ...
        params.get("schedules").each { saveSchedule(it) }
    }

    void saveSchedule(Owner owner, Map schedule) {
        Schedule s 
        if(schedule.get("id") != null) {
            s = Schedule.createCriteria().get {
                eq("owner", owner)
                eq("schedule", schedule.get("seqNo"))
            }
        }

        if(s == null) {
            s = new Schedule()
            schedule.put("seqNo", generateSeqNo(owner))
        }

        s.setProperties(schedule)
        s.save(faileOnError: true)
    }

    Long generateSeqNo(Owner owner) {
        Long seqNo = Schedule.createCriteria().get {
            projections {
                max("seqNo")
            }
            eq("owner", owner)
        }

        if(seqNo == null) { seqNo = 0 }
        return ++seqNo
    }
}
```

Now in the method `generateSeqNo()` always returns the same sequence number. It seems that Hibernate doesn't include by default Domain instances that are not yet flushed on the database. How can I set Grails to include this persisted data only to the queries inside this service?

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the service as [non-transactional](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/services.html) to get over this problem:

```
class MyService {

    static transactional = false

     ...

}
```

You can always make single operations inside transaction if needed.